# How to update part of a combined Observable manually?

Tags: angular, rxjs

To make things easier to illustrate, I have a combined Observable `combinedNotifications$` that I bind to the async pipe. It works nice and well for the first load. HOWEVER. I would like to be able to update `notifications$` ONLY as well manually. So far, I never delved too much into observables as the use-cases were even simpler than this one so far.

```
  combinedNotifications$: Observable<any> = combineLatest([
    this.notifications$,
    this.notificationTypes$
  ]).pipe(
    map((i: any) => ({
      tableData: i[0],
      notificationTypes: i[1]
    })),
    map((f: any) => {
      return ({
        tableData: {
          ...f.tableData, content: f.tableData.content.map((v: any) => ({
            ...v,
            type: f.notificationTypes.eventTypes.find((x: any) => x.value === v.type)?.label,
            cause: f.notificationTypes.causeTypes.find((x: any) => x.value === v.cause)?.label
          }))
        },
        notificationTypes: f.notificationTypes
      })
    }),
    tap((d) => console.log(d)),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

I have a table that I interact with via pagination. Before I created this combined observable, I used to be able to update just the notifications:

```
retrieveNotificationsPage(queryArgs: Pageable = {}, searchData: any = {}) {
    this._loading$.next(true);
    const actionAuditLogsPage$ = this.apiService
      .retrieveNotificationsView$(queryArgs, { ...searchData })
      .pipe(
        delay(300),
        tap({
          complete: () => {
            this._loading$.next(false);
          },
          error: (err) => {
            this._loading$.next(false);
            throw err;
          }
        }),
        catchError((err) => of({ error: err })),
        // shareReplay()
      );
    return actionAuditLogsPage$;
  }
```

Which then got called somewhat like this...

```
 loadRecords(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    ...
    this.notifications$ = this.retrieveNotificationsPage({
      page: isNaN(selectedPage) ? 0 : selectedPage,
      ...(maxPageRowSize != null ? { size: maxPageRowSize } : {})
    }, this.searchForm.value);
  }
```

So I thought I could probably do it with merge, but it only seems to be stuck in an infinite loop...

```
this.combinedNotifications$ = merge(notificationPage$, this.combinedNotifications$);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `notificationTypes` and `notifications` to be loaded once on subscribe (via `async` pipe) and then continue loading `notifications` on demand.

There are a few ways to do this that differ in detail, here is an example how this can be done:

```
export class App {
  // this thing we want to load only once on page load
  private notificationTypes$ = this.retrieveNotificationTypes();
  // this thing we want to load once on page load and then on some action
  private notifications$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<Notification>>(
    // calling the method does not send a request immediately
    // but returns an observable that sends a request when subscribed
    this.retrieveNotificationsPage()
  );

  combinedNotifications$: Observable<any> = combineLatest({
    // pipe to switchMap "unwraps" an observable,
    // you may want to change it to concatMap or mergeMap depending on requerments
    notifications: this.notifications$.pipe(switchMap(identity)),
    notificationTypes: this.notificationTypes$,
  }).pipe(
    map((value) => JSON.stringify(value)), // Just making it readable in the template
    shareReplay(1) // ensures we subscribe only once
  );

  loadRecords() {
    this.notifications$.next(this.retrieveNotificationsPage());
  }

  private retrieveNotificationsPage(): Observable<Notification> {
    return of({ type: 'default', id: currentNotificationId++ }).pipe(
      delay(1000),
      tap(() => console.log('Notifications loaded'))
    );
  }

  private retrieveNotificationTypes(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(['default']).pipe(
      delay(2000),
      tap(() => console.log('Types loaded'))
    );
  }
}
```

The key thing is using a `Subject`, in my case I used `BehaviorSubject` because I can put an initial value there. And it is a `Subject` that emits observables, that then are unwrapped with `switchMap(identity)` and make the actual calls.

Alternatively, the `Subject` may emit objects representing parameters for the API calls, so that then they can be transformed as `switchMap(params => makeACall(...params))`.

[Here is a playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zsgjmb) with the code from above.

Comment: I like this solution even more, as it doesn't require esoteric solutions. Thanks for the playground example!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to update `this.notifications$` manually and ensure that `combinedNotifications$` reflects these changes without affecting the original behavior of `combinedNotifications$` when it updates due to changes in `notifications$` and `notificationTypes$`.

To achieve this, you can use the `startWith` operator to emit an initial value for `combinedNotifications$` and then use the `merge` operator to merge the stream of manual updates with the original `combinedNotifications$` stream. Then, you can use the `distinctUntilChanged` operator to ensure that only distinct values are emitted to avoid infinite loops.

```js
import { merge, of } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Assuming notificationPage$ is the observable returned by retrieveNotificationsPage

// Manual update trigger
const manualUpdate$ = new Subject<void>();

// Observable to handle manual updates
const manualUpdateNotifications$ = manualUpdate$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.retrieveNotificationsPage())
);

// Combine manual updates with original notifications$
const updatedNotifications$ = merge(
  manualUpdateNotifications$,
  this.notifications$.pipe(
    // Filter out initial emission
    startWith(null),
    // Distinct until changed to prevent infinite loops
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
);

// Recreate combinedNotifications$ using the updated notifications$
this.combinedNotifications$ = combineLatest([
  updatedNotifications$,
  this.notificationTypes$
]).pipe(
  map((i: any) => ({
    tableData: i[0],
    notificationTypes: i[1]
  })),
  map((f: any) => ({
    tableData: {
      ...f.tableData,
      content: f.tableData.content.map((v: any) => ({
        ...v,
        type: f.notificationTypes.eventTypes.find((x: any) => x.value === v.type)?.label,
        cause: f.notificationTypes.causeTypes.find((x: any) => x.value === v.cause)?.label
      }))
    },
    notificationTypes: f.notificationTypes
  })),
  tap((d) => console.log(d)),
  shareReplay(1)
);

// Function to trigger manual updates
triggerManualUpdate() {
  manualUpdate$.next();
}
```

With this setup, `this.combinedNotifications$` will reflect changes from both automatic updates (due to changes in `notifications$` and `notificationTypes$` and manual updates triggered by calling `triggerManualUpdate()`. Each update will be distinct, preventing infinite loops.

Comment: I knew I had missed something integral here. Thanks! StartsWith and the ManualTrigger via Subject were the solution for me. Not quite sure why this made the difference here.

Comment: How can we compete with guys generating answers using ChatGPT?

Comment: @Shlang I want to believe they did not. At least in my attempt with ChatGPT I wasn't offered a solution like that.

Comment: @Shlang How can you come up with such a conclusion?